# Defining user type, single table inheritance (?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two types of users: managers, and employees. I use one User controller for both of them.

What I did was add :manager_id to the user table, and put the following in the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :employees, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :manager_id
belongs_to :manager, :class_name => 'User'
```

Sounds simple enough.

But now I want to define the user type. If an user has a manager, he is an employee. If a user has no manager, he is a manager.

What do I need to add to the model so I reference the user type in my views like such:

```
<% if current_user.manager? %>
You are a manager.
<% else %>
You are not a manager.
<% end %>
```

I tried to define the user type in the user.rb model but I'm getting an "undefined method 'manager?' for nil:NilClass" error :

```
def manager?
    manager_id.nil?
end

def employee?
    !manager?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ryan Bigg said, you need to check out the error message a little closer. It isn't that `manager?` doesn't exist as a method on an instance of `User`, it's that it doesn't exist on `Nil`. When there isn't a `current_user`, `current_user` returns `nil`, which you then call `manager?` on.

Try this to avoid this error:

```
<% if current_user && current_user.manager? %>
  Manager!
<% elsif current_user %>
  Not a manager, but a user!
<% else %>
  Not even a user.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your `current_user` object is `nil`, which results in the error you're getting. You will want to check that the user is logged in first before trying to call a method on `current_user`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My original plan was actually to store them in a role field, but the employees needed to belong to managers since I want to have a limit on the number of employees each manager can have. Someone from here pointed out that having a manager_id field would be the best way to go about doing it.